# Удаление всех ссылок с текста

Tags: php

Знатоки, помогите решить задачу.
Есть строка, например:

```
www.google.com.ua?frm=2&scn=3&page=1 какой то текст http://www.google.com.ua какой то текст google.com какой то текст www.google.com какой то текст ....
```

Нужно вырезать все эти текстовые ссылки оставив не тронутым текст. 
Перекопал гугл.. Потерял счет страницам.. то не работает, то вырезает вообще все. Вообщем беда.
Последнее мое достижение:

```
function delete_link ($str) 
{
    $reg = '/[href?|url?|http?|https?|www?|\.ru|\.com|\.net|\.info|\.org|\.ua].+/i';
    if (preg_match($reg, $str)) {
        return preg_replace($reg, '_ссылка_', $str);
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

в этом коде беда в том, что когда он находит ссылку, то удаляет, но вместе с остальным, если он есть, текстом который есть после ссылки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo delete_link('www. google. com.ua?frm=2&scn=3&page=1 какой то текст http://www. google. com.ua какой то текст google.com какой то текст www.google.com какой то текст ....');


function delete_link($str)
{
    $reg = '~(?:https?://)?(?:www\h*\.\h*)?(?:\w+\h*\.\h*){1,2}(?:ru|com|net|info|org|ua)\S*~i';

    return preg_replace($reg, '_ссылка_', $str);
}
```

Comment: Текст между ссылками удаляется...

Comment: @ЮраБирюков подкорректировал ответ.

Comment: А можно как то учесть пробелы https://www . google . com/ для особо умных пользователей..

Comment: @ЮраБирюков подкорректировал ответ (добавил пробелы)

Comment: Как часы.. Благодарю)